# Scroll bar stays on top when scrolling in an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm quite new to web development. I have a page that displays another page in an iFrame. On certain pages when you scroll down using keyboard or mouse wheel the scroll bar sticks to the top even though the page is scrolling down. On other pages it works normally with the scroll bar moving down. What is causing the iFrame to do this?

I recreated the same problem when using the iFrame to link to the apple site which is used in the examples below.

Examples

Scrollbar not working:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        iframe {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        .tcontent{
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

         #header, #footer{
                position:fixed;
                height: 56px;
                display:block;
                width: 100%;
                background: #333;
                z-index:9;
                text-align:center;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                /*padding: 20px 0 0 0;*/
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tcontent">

        <iframe src="http://apple.com/mac/" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzk4u80p/

Scrollbar working:

http://jsfiddle.net/b1qqotjq/

Comment: Have you tested this in other browsers? If so, is the behavior the same?

Comment: Tested with Safari and Chrome on OSX. The behavior is the same.

Comment: With iframes, you may end up with a scroll bar on the main parent document and in the iframe itself. Which scroll bar is sticking?

Comment: Using Windows Chrome, the above Fiddles both seemed to work fine.

Comment: How am I able to find out which scrollbar it is?

Comment: It is difficult for me to tell because I am not seeing what you are. But one thing I notice is that in the Fiddle you posted, the bottom section with the gradient overflows down out of the view and there is no scroll bar. By adding `overflow: auto;` to the `#footer`, I get a scroll bar there.

Comment: You might try `scrolling="auto"` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Ive tried adding the overflow to the footer. I also removed the footer all together and just have the iframe in the tcontent div and iframe as well as setting the scrolling attribute to auto and it is reproducing the same effect with the scrollbar.